# How to set Cosmos DB account level RUs via ARM with Table API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager

I want to set the throughput for the whole Cosmos database rather than by container.

This wouldn't be so hard if I were using the SQL mode but I'm using Table mode.

A table, AFAIK, maps to a container. So I *do not* want to set the throughput on each table.

The reference documentation for ARM is shocking. The resource `type` in the quick-start sample [isn't even documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/allversions).

Here's what I can see for setting the RUs for a whole SQL mode DB.

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/settings",
    "name": "[concat(variables('cosmosAccountName'), '/sql/', parameters('cosmosDatabaseName'), '/throughput')]",
    "apiVersion": "2016-03-31",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts', parameters('cosmosAccountName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "resource": {
            "throughput": "[parameters('cosmosThroughput')]"
        }
    }
},
```

The problem is that I don't know what value I need for `name`, since I'm using tables. I don't want to name a specific table, I want the RUs to apply across the database, or "account" as is the language used in the portal.

```
"type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/settings",
"name": "[concat(variables('cosmosAccountName'), '/sql/', parameters('cosmosDatabaseName'), '/throughput')]",
```

I have done this in the portal, its a single switch, but if I export the template from the portal it contains no config for the RUs at all.

---

### Trials and Errors

Using this name.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('cosmosAccountName'), '/sql/', 'TablesDB', '/throughput')]",
```

I get.

> Requests for API sql are not supported for this account.

Using this name.

```
"name": "[concat(parameters('cosmosAccountName'), '/table/', 'TablesDB', '/throughput')]",
```

I get.

> Required Header authorization is missing. Ensure a valid Authorization token is passed.

Strange that one. I'd not expect to see that from `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` which is authenticated and able to change other resources in the template.